# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbn'

Tags: python-3.x

I need to use "Deep belief Network" in python 3.7.10 through spyder in a virtual environment. so I used the following command :

***from dbn.tensorflow import SupervisedDBNClassification***

when running the program it gives me the message :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbn' even after installing DBN module using "pip install dbn"or "pip install DBN"
knowing that I checked the path of the module.

Answer (score 2):

According to PyPI you've installed the module [Decentralized-Bluetooth-Network](https://pypi.org/project/DBN/)
Please check the [GitHub](https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network) page of the maintainer, to find the installation instructions.

For using the module in a virtual environment:
https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network#the-virtualenv-way