# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbn' error

Tags: tensorflow, data-mining

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dbn.tensorflow import SupervisedDBNClassification
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.classification import accuracy_score


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbn
```

*When I try sorting malware dataset with using Deep belief network I get this error
I try everything but i can't fix it*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657294/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-dbn)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to git clone the repo, enter the folder, install requirements and run your code inside the folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network.git
cd deep-belief-network
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 543026528.py
```

dbn is a folder inside the deep-belief-network folder